# When passing collection to EditorFor, Is it possible to access the index without using 'for'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.List)
```

I want my application to be able to remove record from the list hence the need of index otherwise it won't be able to detect which index to remove from the list.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why would property `List` contain elements that you don't want to render?

Comment: If you really want to filter out elements, you could use a  Linq Where to apply a predicate before handing to an Editor Template, e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.List.Where(l => ! l.SomeConditionYouDontWant))`. But as per Stephen, the controller should have already determined the filtered list.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: for example I have an empty list, now I have a button that if clicked will populate the list, but I also have a button to remove added object in the list which is why I need the index.

Comment: Then you need to read the answer I gave in the link to your last question. You need to generate a hidden input with `name="Index"` that has a value matching the indexer of your properties, which allows you to post back non-consecutive indexers. You cant do that with an `EditorTemplate`, but you can use `for` loop or the `BeginCollectionItem` helper

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer your question though I didn't get it entirely.

Use : `Html.NameFor(x=>x.FieldName)` // This will give you List[index].FieldName

Now you can pass it to your js function to remove/apply the logic on this field.

Example

`<span onclick='RemoveRecord(this,'@Html.NameFor(m => m.FieldName)' )' >Remove</span>`

JS function

```
 function RemoveRecord(currentElement, fieldName)
    {
        var parentTr = $(currentElement).parent('tr');//assuming you have tr..td structure
            $("[name='"+fieldName+"']").val('');//clear the value
            parentTr.hide();
    }
```